# Porting old C project into C++/CX

Tags: c, porting, c++-cx

I'm rather new to C++/CX, and right now have an old C project which I need to port into C++/CX.

The output are flushed into text-file or standard output, but it's not that important right now since I can just take them into the Message Dialog there.

My question is that, do you have any tips for porting this project?

I just tried to copy a C file into CPP but failed to compile.

I mean, do I need to wrap the old functions into some kind of Class structure now?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How exactly did it fail? What was the error message? Did you take into account differences between C and normal C++ (like having to cast the result of `malloc`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the differences between C and C++, a starting point is David Tribble's ["C99 vs C++98"](http://david.tribble.com/text/cdiffs.htm). Without any more details (original C environment, current C++ environment, some details on exact error messages) it is next to impossible to answer the question.

Comment: +1: In my experience of converting C files to C++ (recently, over 128 of them), the job is mostly one of fixing compile errors. Without knowing what problems the OP ran into, I see no way to answer this question.